# Name of karma yogis who attained self realization in past while living in world?

Tags: karma, moksha, janaka

I want to know name of karma yogis
Who attained self realization while doing karma yoga and living in world(sansaar)

For Eg:- Raja janak was brahma gnani and a karma yogi who remained in world even after attaining brahma gyaan.

Comment: You want to know names of some such Karma Yogis or all of them?

Comment: @Rickross ji whatever names you know you can provide with what occupation they were doing

Comment: Ok, I just asked for clarification. If you had said you want the names of all of them then it would have made the question too broad.

Comment: @Rickross pls ans if you know.

Comment: Sorry I don't know @ Harsh

Answer (score 1):

Manu and Ikshvaku

> Bhagavad Gita 4.1 The Supreme Lord Shree Krishna said: I taught this
> eternal science of Yog to the Sun God, Vivasvan, who passed it on to
> Manu; and Manu, in turn, instructed it to Ikshvaku